# SQL query gives Incorrect syntax near ')' - use of CAST in INNER JOIN

Tags: sql-server, casting, syntax-error, inner-join

I get the error Incorrect syntax near ')' from the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
"GLPOST"."ACCTID",
"GLPOST"."FISCALYR",
"GLPOST"."FISCALPERD",
"GLPOST"."SRCELEDGER",
"GLPOST"."JRNLDATE",
"GLPOST"."BATCHNBR",
"GLPOST"."ENTRYNBR",
"GLPOST"."JNLDTLDESC",
"GLPOST"."JNLDTLREF",
"GLPOST"."TRANSAMT",
"APIBC"."POSTSEQNBR",
"APIBC"."CNTBTCH"

FROM ("MHLDAT"."dbo"."GLPOST" "GLPOST" 
INNER JOIN "MHLDAT"."dbo"."GLJEH" "GLJEH"
ON (("GLPOST"."DRILSRCTY"="GLJEH"."DRILSRCTY") 
AND ("GLPOST"."DRILLDWNLK"="GLJEH"."DRILLDWNLK") 
AND "GLPOST"."DRILAPP"="GLJEH"."DRILAPP"))) 
INNER JOIN "MHLDAT"."dbo"."APIBC" "APIBC" 
ON "APIBC"."POSTSEQNBR" = (CAST ("SUBSTRING" (CAST ("GLPOST"."DRILLDWNLK" AS "CHAR"(18)),3,CAST ("LEFT" (CAST ("GLPOST"."DRILLDWNLK" AS "CHAR"(18)),1) AS "INT" )) AS "INT" )) 

WHERE  
    "GLPOST"."SRCELEDGER"=N'AP' AND "GLPOST"."FISCALYR"=N'2021' AND "GLPOST"."FISCALPERD"=N'01' AND "GLJEH"."ERRBATCH"=0
```

Any suggestions to resolve please?

Comment: Format your code? We can't read it as it stands...

Comment: Wow - unusual to use double quotes with SQL... not very common. 1) Remove all the brackets from the `from` and `join`s. 2) Don't quote `substring` and `left` as they are functions not datatypes. See what you get after that.

Comment: What does a value in GLPOST.DRILLDWNLK look like? And what does a matching value in APIBC.POSTSEQNBR look like?

Comment: Chop code until it is OK then add back minimal code to get the error. Then research the error. [ask] [help] [mre] PS "Mininmal"

Comment: What's with the double quotes and uncessary brackets???

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    GLPOST.ACCTID,
    GLPOST.FISCALYR,
    GLPOST.FISCALPERD,
    GLPOST.SRCELEDGER,
    GLPOST.JRNLDATE,
    GLPOST.BATCHNBR,
    GLPOST.ENTRYNBR,
    GLPOST.JNLDTLDESC,
    GLPOST.JNLDTLREF,
    GLPOST.TRANSAMT,
    APIBC.POSTSEQNBR,
    APIBC.CNTBTCH    
FROM MHLDAT.dbo.GLPOST  
    INNER JOIN MHLDAT.dbo.GLJEH 
        ON     GLPOST.DRILSRCTY=GLJEH.DRILSRCTY
           AND GLPOST.DRILLDWNLK=GLJEH.DRILLDWNLK
           AND GLPOST.DRILAPP=GLJEH.DRILAPP
    INNER JOIN MHLDAT.dbo.APIBC 
         ON    APIBC.POSTSEQNBR = CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(GLPOST.DRILLDWNLK AS CHAR(18)),
                                                 3,
                                                 CAST(LEFT(CAST(GLPOST.DRILLDWNLK AS CHAR(18)),
                                                           1) AS INT)
                                                 ) AS INT)        
WHERE  
        GLPOST.SRCELEDGER = N'AP' 
    AND GLPOST.FISCALYR = N'2021' 
    AND GLPOST.FISCALPERD = N'01' 
    AND GLJEH.ERRBATCH = 0
```

You are using a lot of unnecessary parenthesis and double quoting, remove them (specially on the names of the functions SUBSTRING and LEFT). Remove the aliases (they are unnecessary because you use the same name as the table).

I have aligned your query so you can visually see where starts and ends every subexpression.

Comment: Thanks Marc - removing the double quotes solved my problem. As you suggested I also removed a few parenthesis.  Have also removed some of the aliases.